# If condition using angular js

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

I have a value `{{category}}` which is to printed using angular js. Based on the value I have to change the contents of div.

```
if {{category}} = "aa" then <div>aa</div>
if {{category}} = "bb" then <div>bb</div>
```

how is this possible.

Comment: Why not something like <div>{{category}}</div> is this what you are looking for? Or the value of category is not what you actually want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<div ng-if="category === 'aa'">aa</div>
<div ng-if="category === 'bb'">bb</div>
```

Or:

```
<div>{{category}}</div>
```

Comment: It worked for me.
My implemented code is 
<span ng-if="category == 'clothes'"><img src="images/Clothes.jpg" id="img"/></span>
     <span ng-if="category == 'books and media'"><img src="images/books.jpg" id="img"/></span>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply show

```
<div>{{category}}</div>
```

No need to check